# How to associate JPA entities with PersistenceUnits

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I have two persistenceUnits mapping to two different Oracle schema, the schemas are similar but with different table names. When I try to deploy my application,I get a Hibernate Exception "Missing Table", it seems like Hibernate is looking for table in the wrong persistenceUnit.

> .ear#POIPersistenceUnit\": org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: POI_SERVICE
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: POI_SERVICE"}}

the table "POI_SERVICE" belongs to "POIExtractorPersistenceUnit" persistenceUnit not "POIPersistenceUnit" persistenceUnit

I have tried listing the entities with the respective persistenceUnits in the persistence.xml file as follows but with no luck, still getting the same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="POIExtractorPersistenceUnit">

    <jta-data-source>java:/XAPOIExtractorDS</jta-data-source>

    <class>za.co.fnb.cii.poiextractor.persistence.model.IdentificationRequest</class>
    <class>za.co.fnb.cii.poiextractor.persistence.model.IdentificationResponse</class>
    <class>za.co.fnb.cii.poiextractor.persistence.model.POIService</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="POIPersistenceUnit">

    <jta-data-source>java:/XACompendiumDS</jta-data-source>

    <class>za.co.fnb.cii.poiextractor.persistence.entities.IdentificationRequestIncoming</class>
    <class>za.co.fnb.cii.poiextractor.persistence.entities.IdentificationResponseIncoming</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

I have also tried to annotate the entities as follows `@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "POIExtractorPersistenceUnit")` but still no luck, the error is still there.

```
/**
 * Created by on 21-Dec-15.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "POI_SERVICE")
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "POIExtractorPersistenceUnit")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name="findServiceRecordByApplicationName",
                query="SELECT pois FROM POIService pois WHERE pois.application = :applicationName")
})
public class POIService implements IEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="service_config_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="service_config_seq", sequenceName="service_config_seq", allocationSize=1)
    private long id;

    private String application;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "last_update",nullable = false)
    private Date lastUpdate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "last_date",nullable = true)
    private Date lastDate;

    @Column(name = "last_record",nullable = true)
    private long lastRecord;

    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    public void setApplication(String application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public Date getLastDate() {
        return lastDate;
    }

    public void setLastDate(Date lastDate) {
        this.lastDate = lastDate;
    }

    public long getLastRecord() {
        return lastRecord;
    }

    public void setLastRecord(long lastRecord) {
        this.lastRecord = lastRecord;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Stacktrace

> 2016-01-08 12:24:52,587 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000262: Table not found:
>   POI_SERVICE 2016-01-08 12:24:52,590 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."poiextractor-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear#POIPersistenceUnit":
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."poiextractor-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear#POIPersistenceUnit":
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: POI_SERVICE  at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
>   [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
>   [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]     at
>   org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474)
>   [wildfly-security-manager-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
>   [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]     at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
>   [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final] Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: POI_SERVICE  at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1335)
>   [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
>   [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:525)
>   [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
>   [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
>   [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
>   [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
>   [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]     ... 8 more
>
> 2016-01-08 12:24:58,786 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool
>   -- 57) HHH000261: Table found: POIOPS.POI_SERVICE 2016-01-08 12:24:58,788 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) HHH000037: Columns: [last_record,
>   application, last_update, id, last_date] 2016-01-08 12:25:00,774 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool
>   -- 57) HHH000261: Table found: POIOPS.IDENTIFICATION_REQUEST 2016-01-08 12:25:00,775 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool
>   -- 57) HHH000037: Columns: [sworkstationid, yafp2wsqimage, stransactiontime, created, stype, bretphoto, scardseqno, stranid,
>   breturnname, smode, requesttype, ssiteid, identificationresponse_id,
>   sidn, id, yafp1wsqimage, updated, ifpind1, ifpind2] 2016-01-08
>   12:25:05,385 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) HHH000261: Table found:
>   POIOPS.IDENTIFICATION_RESPONSE 2016-01-08 12:25:05,387 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool
>   -- 57) HHH000037: Columns: [bnameret, created, sfpind2, scallcentreno, ifp2score, stranid, sidissuedate, ierror, ifp1score, sfp1result, sidn,
>   sname, serror, sfp2result, sfpind1, yaphoto, ssmartcardind, id,
>   ssurname, updated] 2016-01-08 12:25:09,367 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool
>   -- 57) HHH000261: Table found: POIOPS.IDENTIFICATIONREQUEST 2016-01-08 12:25:09,369 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) HHH000037: Columns: [sworkstationid,
>   responseerror, yafp2wsqimage, stransactiontime, created, stype,
>   bretphoto, scardseqno, stranid, breturnname, smode, requesttype,
>   ssiteid, sidn, id, yafp1wsqimage, updated, ifpind1, ifpind2]
>   2016-01-08 12:25:15,851 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool
>   -- 57) HHH000261: Table found: POIOPS.IDENTIFICATIONRESPONSE 2016-01-08 12:25:15,853 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool
>   -- 57) HHH000037: Columns: [bnameret, created, sfpind2, scallcentreno, ifp2score, stranid, sidissuedate, ierror, ifp1score, sfp1result, sidn,
>   sname, serror, sfp2result, sfpind1, yaphoto, ssmartcardind, id,
>   ssurname, updated, request_id] 2016-01-08 12:25:15,994 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy")
>   failed - address: ([("deployment" =>
>   "poiextractor-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) - failure description:
>   {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"poiextractor-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear#POIPersistenceUnit\""
>   => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"poiextractor-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear#POIPersistenceUnit\":
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: POI_SERVICE
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: POI_SERVICE"}} 2016-01-08 12:25:15,996 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server]
>   (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment
>   "poiextractor-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" was rolled back with the
>   following failure message:  {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"poiextractor-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear#POIPersistenceUnit\""
>   => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"poiextractor-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear#POIPersistenceUnit\":
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: POI_SERVICE
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: POI_SERVICE"}} 2016-01-08 12:25:15,997 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6)
>   JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name =
>   poiextractor-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear_org.h2.Driver_1_4 2016-01-08
>   12:25:15,998 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool --
>   57) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service
>   'poiextractor-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear#POIExtractorPersistenceUnit'
>   2016-01-08 12:25:16,018 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service
>   thread 1-9) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment
>   poiextractor-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear 2016-01-08 12:25:16,043 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) JBAS011410:
>   Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service
>   'poiextractor-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear#POIPersistenceUnit' 2016-01-08
>   12:25:16,043 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool --
>   59) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service
>   'poiextractor-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear#POIExtractorPersistenceUnit'

**UPDATE 2:**
When I remove this property from the persistence.xml everything works fine.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
```

Comment: Can you include the stack trace for the missing table please.  I would suspect that the "missing" table is required by one of the persistent units.

Comment: You mentioned that the tables are in different schemas. For a start you should specify the schema name in the @Table annotation

Comment: And the PersistenceUnit annotation can be removed again from the entities, that is entirely not the place to use that annotation.

Comment: @DuranWesleyHarris I tried your solution but no luck, I ended up removing the '<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />' property which worked.

Comment: So that means the table didn't actually exist yet.. makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JPA `EntityManager` belongs to one persistence unit, or `EntityManagerFactory`, You can't mix multiple persistence units with the same `EntityManager`.

But you don't have to do that.

You can have a single persistence unit and use the `schema` attribute when mapping entities.

If you use multiple persistence units, you need multiple `persistence.xml`, multiple `EntityManagerFactory` and probably JTA if you need to global transactions.